# jQuery Nested Sortable - Nesting just works for last child

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, plugins

I have a problem with the nested sortable jQuery UI plugin by Manuele J Sarfatti. It's just possible to nest children in the last ol of a level. I extended the plugin a bit to work with handles ( grabbed the first level item within all childhandles before) by overriding _mouseCapture (based on the original UI Code).

But maybe I'm doing something wrong in general. I've created a JSFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/vhMB4/

```
$(".group").nestedSortable({
    connectWith: ".group",
    handle: ".handle",
    handleItemClosestTarget: "li",
    placeholder: "placeholder",
    maxLevels: 8
});
```

Try to drag the item "Test 13" in "Test 11". Never got such problems with this plugin before.

Any ideas?

jQUery: 1.7.2

jQuery-UI: 1.8.2

jQuery UI Nested Sortable: 1.3.5

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a style problem. I removed margin from the li-elements and removed float:left from the handles..... Never thought it could be that easy....